# Bitmap display in mips

Tags: bitmap, mips, display

How is bitmap display done in mips assembly language and we made a blackjack game.

but somehow we couldn't add bitmap display to our code via mars emulator, we couldn't show the cards. Can anyone help with this? We tried a lot we couldn't do it.

Comment: You need to (1) connect the bit map display to the emulator, and (2) write to the display as if it were memory locations.  Each (32-bit) word is one pixel on the display

Comment: I'm not familiar with the mars simulator but many computers work like this: Think of the screen as an array of pixels. The 0th entry in the array is the top left corner of the screen. The 1st entry is the pixel to the right of that, the 2nd entry is the pixel to the right of the first, and so on. The value you write in each entry in the array tells the computer what color you want that pixel to be.